# How do you modify the contents for username, password, and domain of a selected auth profile?

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api

I have the following profile "TPG" for a REST Request already selected and set at the framework level:

[Auth Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE1Km.png)
[image]

How do I modify the username, password, and domain fields; along with changing the choice between the two options for Pre-emptive auth in a standalone groovy script?

Answer (score 0):

Use [property expansion](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html) so that value can be picked from custom properties of either test case or test suite or project.

For example using test case level custom properties -

- create a custom property at test case say **USER** and define its value
- similarly, create another property for password say **PWD** and define its value
- now set `${#TestCase#USER}`, `${#TestCase#PWD}` for Username and Password of Auth profile respectively

Use below groovy script to update the values for username and password :

```
context.testCase.setProperty('USER',newUsernameValue)
context.testCase.setProperty('PWD',newPasswordValue)
```

Comment: The problem I had with this solution, is that it seems to be modifying the fields for the built in profile NTLM. not the custom profile I had selected prior.

Comment: Can't understand your comment.

Comment: Essentially I tried using property expansion to modify the custom properties, but the username, password, and domain for the profile TPG remained the same, with no changes.

Comment: Can you show the screen shot along with raw request?

Comment: :Here is my script: http://oi64.tinypic.com/25rm9n9.jpg Here is my raw request, it's just pinging a server: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=27wvogj&s=9

Comment: some how these images are not being shown, those pages are having just ads.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this information is a custom properties in the TestStep.

When you create a testStep with authentication the soapUI generate a singular custom properties(*Domain,Username,Password*) 
[image: auth soupUI custom properties]

The groovy script for to change this properties will be:

```
//Print Values Properties
    log.info  testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('NAME_TestStepRequest').getPropertyList().name;
    log.info  testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('NAME_TestStepRequest').getPropertyList().value;
    log.info  testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('NAME_TestStepRequest').getPropertyValue("Username");
    log.info  testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('NAME_TestStepRequest').getPropertyValue("Password");
    log.info  testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('NAME_TestStepRequest').getPropertyValue("Domain");
    // SET Properties
    testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('NAME_TestStepRequest').setPropertyValue("Username","B");
    testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('NAME_TestStepRequest').setPropertyValue("Password","B");
    testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('NAME_TestStepRequest').setPropertyValue("Domain","B");
// Get new Values
    log.info  testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('NAME_TestStepRequest').getPropertyValue("Username");
    log.info  testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('NAME_TestStepRequest').getPropertyValue("Password");
    log.info  testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('NAME_TestStepRequest').getPropertyValue("Domain");
```